# Why doesn't an orphan process receive signals?

Tags: signals, job-control, trap

I have two shell scripts: `launch_job.sh` and `sub_job.sh`.

If `launch_job.sh` uses the following method to run `sub_job.sh`:

```
nohup sub_job.sh &
```

`sub_job.sh` becomes an orphan, i.e. with PPID 1.
I discovered that such process doesn't receive signals, except SIGKILL. 
I guess there is some explanation for this, but I couldn't find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As long as this parent is alive, it can handle the stopping and starting of members in the process group. When it dies, there may be nobody to continue stopped processes. that why they dont receive any other signal other than SIGKILL
see http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html for details